# Java Modules: Have access to a access to an object but unable to create the object

Tags: java, module, visibility, instantiation

Let's say I have 2 Modules.

One called "Receiver" and one called "Modifier".

In the Receiver module I have a package called "com.danii.Receiver", with a class called "DataReceiver". And I have another package in the Receiver module called "com.danii.Entities", with a class called "Data". The Receiver module currently only exports com.danii.Receiver.

The class DataReceiver, when I run a function in it, will create a new Data object, and send it back.

In my Modifier module, I have it set to require com.danii.Receiver, and I wish to receive some Data via DataReceiver. I try to do this, but no matter what I do I cannot read it because it doesn't have access to the Data class.

How can I have access to read the Data DataReceiver gives me, but still not able to create Data?

Comment: Exporting is only half of the process.  The Modifier module needs to declare `requires com.danii.Receiver;` in its module-info.java.

Comment: I've done that, I should probably clarify that, sorry @VGR.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  You must export every package whose classes you wish to make accessible by other modules.  So, you need `exports com.danii.Entities;` in addition to exporting com.danii.Receiver.

Comment: @VGR Doing that would make Data instantiate-able. As I said I do not want the Modifier module to be able to create Data, only receive it.

Comment: I see.  I thought you were asking *why* you could not instantiate Data, but you were actually asking *how* to prevent instantiation of Data by other modules.  In that case, Ryan’s answer is correct (except that you should never preface an interface name with an `I`).

Comment: Yes, I wasn't really trying to recommend `IData` as the name, just something to use other than `Data` in my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that would allow you to keep most aspects of your current structure would be to have another exported package with an interface implemented by Data (I'll call it IData for now). Then DataReceiver can return an IData object (implementation would still be via the Data class). IData could be in its own exported package or in the Receiver package that you are already exporting.